# MySQL schedule update syintax wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, random, schedule

I'm trying to set a trigger in my MySQL database, so I'm using below query:

```
CREATE EVENT pwdupdate
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE
DO
    UPDATE 'passwords'
    SET 'pass'= SUBSTRING((RAND())
```

Basically I want it to update the pass field of a table with a random string, but it keeps telling me that there's a syintax error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''passwords' SET 'pass'= SUBSTRING((RAND())' at line 5

Any help ?

**EDIT :** I removed the single quotes as suggested, but still the error remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need single quotes for table and column name and its invalid in mysql however you can use backticks ``

```
UPDATE passwords
    SET pass= substring(RAND(),8)
```

Comment: substring needs the 2nd argument as the number of characters you need that check the updated answer !